# zsh / bash - How to write directories of all open terminal tabs to file?

Tags: bash, zsh

I would like to write the working directory of every terminal tab to a single file. I think I've come close with the following, but the problem is that the same (current) directory path is written to the file multiple times.

```
for x in $(ps | grep zsh)
do
  echo "$(pwd)" >> "tabs open $(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S).txt"
done
```

Thanks in advance for putting up with my newbish question.

Comment: What do you mean every terminal tab? Also pretty sure what you are trying is impossible. Processes can't see other processes environment variables. The best you would probably get is checking `/proc/$pid/environ` for the process, but I'm pretty sure shells don't update that after starting, so it wouldn't contain PWD.

Comment: Well shucks . . . .

Comment: `/proc/$pid/cwd` is a symlink to the current working directory of the given process. This assumes you have a `proc` filesystem, of course.

Comment: @123 The bash profile could be changed to perform a command every time the prompt eh... is prompted. Thus, the `$PWD` could be tracked... (About zsh, I don't know.)

Comment: @chepner Oh yeah, forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a 100% solution to what you need but it's closest that I can understand.

```
# For each PID of the "-bash" processes...
for x in $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -- "-bash" | awk '{print $2}'); do 
    # check if the file is readable (only user has access)
    if [[ -r /proc/$x/cwd ]]; then
        # print details including the working directory
        ls -ld /proc/$x/cwd
        # ... or just PID and it's working directory
        echo $x : $(ls -ld /proc/$x/cwd | awk '{print $11}')
    fi
done > "tabs_open_$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S).txt"
```

"-bash" is the process names as it looks when it's actually inside a terminal. The script will not take into consideration "bash" processes started manually by the user inside a terminal window.